# Using JSON decode PHP 5.3

Tags: php, json

My web host is running PHP 5.3, but for some reason I cannot use Json_decode(). Why is that? How can I make it work? Are there any alternatives to Json_decode()?

I am using it like this:

```
$data= json_decode($_POST['moment']);
var_dump($_POST['moment']);
foreach($data as $item) {
echo $item;
```

And it outputs this: 
string(22) "[\"36\",\"37\",\"38\"]" 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 23

By doing the var_dump() I see the string is created, but I cannot get json_decode to work, to create the array $data

Thanks

Comment: Did you check for PHP errors during the execution of your script?

Comment: "Doesn't work" how? Does it give an "undefined function" error?

Comment: What do you mean you cannot use it? Error? IT says no?

Comment: please give more details json extension is part of php5.3. What is the error message you are receiving?

Comment: It's `json_decode()`, no uppercase letters by the way.

Comment: @moonwave99 it doesn't matter. It's not JavaScript.

Comment: It doesn't even give me an error. It just doesn't output anything.

Comment: Can you please give a var_export of the string you want to decode?

Comment: @AlienWebguy wut, never knew PHP functions to be case insensitive! You always learn something new in our favourite language.

Comment: This is the var_export [\\"36\\",\\"37\\",\\"38\\"]

Comment: in such a way... try `json_decode(stripslashes(<your var>))`

Comment: Please refrain from writing duplicate questions. The [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12332666/911182) provides more context so just update it instead of opening a new one.

Comment: @AlainT I. Love. You. It worked

Answer (score 4):

`json_decode` returns `NULL` when the string you ask it to decode is not valid. You can use `json_last_error` to diagnose the issue.

When you are going to loop an array like that, you should make sure the value is actually an array.

```
$data= json_decode($_POST['moment'], true);
if (!is_array($data)) {
  echo json_error_string(json_last_error());
} else {
    foreach($data as $item) {
        echo $item;
    }
}
```

Based on code from the manual:

```
function json_error_string ($json_error_code) {
   switch ($json_error_code) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            return ' - No errors';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            return ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            return ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            return ' - Unexpected control character found';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            return ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            return ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
        break;
        default:
            return ' - Unknown error';
        break;
    }
}
```

Finally, that you aren't getting any error messages indicates you either have `error_reporting` off or `display_errors` off. You need to enable all error reporting with `error_reporting(E_ALL & E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', '1');`. Remove that from production code, but while you're actively working, you need to be seeing all the information possible about the code you are creating.

**Documentation**

- `json_decode` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
- `json_last_error` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php
- `is_array` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

Comment: +1. You can also use `foreach` on an object too, not just an array, fyi.

Comment: I almost always take the associative array. Having random `stdObject`s floating around your code when you don't normally use them is asking for grief. If you DO use `stdObject` for other stuff, or you're working with functions or methods that take object arguments, it makes sense. Otherwise, I take the array. @AlienWebguy -- you can use an object that implements an iteration interface, yes, but not any old object. stdClass is iterable, but as I said... why bother?

Comment: @user1592953 That means your json string is dirty. Where is it coming from, how is it made?

Comment: @Chris: [Using javascript in a PHP file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12332666/911182) provides the context for this question. I don't know why the OP opened a new question.

Comment: Why can noone explain why I do not have a problem while doing this on my localhost!?

Comment: @user1592953 I suspect -- and I'm just guessing, that it is because you have not provided the information necessary to solve the actual problem. This answer very clearly addresses the question that you asked. It doesn't say anything about localhost because your question does not mention localhost. You asked why json_decode fails, I told you how to find out. Accept some answers, then ask a new question with **all the details**. Otherwise... we don't read minds. If you don't mention localhost, if you don't give code samples and describe your problem thoroughly, how can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it using stripslashes():

```
$objJs = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['obj']));
```